# Notepad++ define line-break (word wrap) rules

Tags: notepad++, word-wrap

When in Notepad++ `word wrap` is enabled, long lines are broken according to some of the following rules:

- After a whitespace character
- Before a forward slash

Otherwise, if necessary, in the middle of a word.

Is it possible to adjust these rules in some way (somwhere in Preferences)? For example, allow word wrap line break to preferentially happen before backslashes, before `&` characters, and so on. Such rules could be interesting for breaking Windows paths or long URLs with GET variables, resp., and help with visibility while editing in np++.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is direct option for manage word wrap. But you can try by changing word delimiter:
Settings->Preferences->Delimiter
[image]